# bootstrap-responsive container width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, containers

I am using bootstrap-responsive and scaffolding successfully, 
my question is if I can increase the container's width and keep the responsive capabilities 
`<div class="container" style="width:1300px">` ?

Answer (score 10):

It seems you want to use the whole width of a wide screen desktop screens... If that's what you want, while keeping it responsive/fluid. Then you may just change your div class to

```
from
<div class="container">

to

<div class="container-fluid">
```

Comment: just to give an update to this answer. this will not be the case in Twitter Bootstrap 3.0

Answer (score 3):

if you are on **bootstrap 3** use `.container-fluid` instead of `.container`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

**reference:-**  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid